# Cannot cast java ArrayList to scala immutable List

Tags: scala

I have the following data structure:

> java.util.Map[List[String],List[String]] = {[10, 20]=[1500], [5, 7]=[1400]}

I am trying to extract the numbers `10 20 5 and 7` using Scala. The way I was looking to achieve this is:

```
map.head._1 -> to extract 10 (map.head returns a tuple)
map.head._2 -> to extract 20 (map.head returns a tuple)
```

However, I am getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to scala.collection.immutable.List
```

I have read about importing `import scala.collection.JavaConversions._` however, this did not fix anything.

Thanks, any help is highly appreciated!

The piece of code that tries to achieve this is:

```
 def getTokenRangeForKeys(params: String): java.util.Map[List[String], List[String]] = {
    invokeOperation[java.util.Map[List[String], List[String]]]("XXX", "YYY", Array(params))
  }
```

The above method returns my map, which looks like this:

```
  map = java.util.Map[List[String],List[String]] = {[10, 20]=[1500], [5, 7]=[1400]}
```

What I have tried so far:

```
map.head._1 -> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to scala.collection.immutable.List

scalaMap = map.asScala
m.headOption match {
  case Some((h1, h2)) => println((h1, h2)) -> java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to scala.collection.immutable.List
  case None => ...
}
```

Comment: Can you show how you're declaring the map?

Comment: Show your code - post a complete piece of code that reproduces the problem, not just a single statement snippet (like `map.head._1` etc.), that will make it much easier to tell what exactly is wrong.

Comment: This is my entire code related to this. A method returns a java Map that needs to be worked with in a Scala script.

Comment: Edit: I've posted the said code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your declaration of what comes from Java world should be:

```
java.util.Map[java.util.List[String], java.util.List[String]]
```

In the current form of `java.util.Map[List[String], List[String]]` you declare a java Map of Scala Lists, which is probably not what you want. JVM is not complaining when you pass your Java types because only top level type is checked as a part of function signature check - this is called type erasure.

On this you should use `JavaConverters` `asScala` to convert to corresponding Scala types as written in the Reactormonk answer:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
val m = map.asScala.map{case (h, k) => (h.asScala, k.asScala)}
```

Comment: This is indeed a solution. It works as expected now!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `JavaConversions`.

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
val m = map.asScala.map({case (h, k) => (h.asScala, k.asScala)})
m.headOption match {
  case Some((h1, h2)) => ...
  case None => ...
}
```

Comment: I see what you are trying to do, but I can't get the syntax write I guess. It's my first ever scala project, could you please provide the additional code that achieves this?

Comment: [On the pattern matching](http://docs.scala-lang.org/cheatsheets/#pattern_matching), I'm using `headOption` so you handle the case of an empty `Map`.

Comment: I get back the same exception. I tried to just print (h1, h2) like this: ... => println((h1, h2))

Comment: h.asScala and k.asScala throw an error: value asScala is not a memeber of List[String]

Comment: What's the fully qualified type of `map`?

Comment: Right click, go to -> type declaration gets me to Map.java, so I would say it's just an implementation of the Map interface ...

Comment: That doesn't help me. The repl usually gives you the fully qualified type.

Comment: map.getClass() -> Class[_ <: java.util.Map[List[String],List[String]]] = class java.util.HashMap